# Setting tooltip to show specific dates based on the field it hovers over?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Is it possible to filter what a tooltip displays based on the content it hovers over?

I am building a progress-tracking dashboard for various projects. I have a view that displays the completion by each department for each project stage (Project Completion Table).

[image]

I also have a table with the start dates of each project stage (Project Dates).

[image]

I wish to have the start dates for each project stage displayed on the tooltip based on the different project stage completion bars that the user hovers over.

[image]

Link to sample workbook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T2O07FHAjN75H4tP03zraYLwrXOOPmiv/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this first; Drag `[Design (sample data2)]` to your [tooltip in the marks pane](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/view_parts.htm#Tooltips).

If this does not give you your desired output then continue reading.

### Using a `FIXED LOD` expression:

Create a calculated field fixed to the project stage level of your data.

```
{FIXED [project stage /*which I assume is your pivot field names from your images*/] : MIN([Project Dates]}
```

***Note:** the MIN is only there as FIXED expressions need to return an aggregated value.*

Drag this calculated field to your tooltip in the marks pane.

Comment: Thanks Muff.

I ended up creating a calculated field with "CASE" to ensure dates for each project phase would show up as the user hovers over the completion bars but I will def keep your solution in mind should I come across this issue again.